# how can I Crawl prepared url lists

Tags: python, web-crawler

I'm going to crawl the web with python
Save urls information as csv or txt
I want to crawl page by page while loading it in code
How can i do this

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

with open('crawlingweb.csv') as f:
    content=f.readlines()
    content=[x.strip() for x in content]

url='#I want to bring url from csv or txt file'
html=urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
text=soup.get_text()
print(text)
```

Comment: you can use for loop for content and do one by one.

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

with open('crawlingweb.csv') as f:
    content=f.readlines()
    content=[x.strip() for x in content]

for i in range(10):
    url=content[i]
    html=urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
    soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
    text=soup.get_text()
    print(text)
```